# Solidworks Long Term Transient Heat Transfer

Tags: heat-transfer, solidworks

I have a cylinder with water, containing an arbitrarily shaped (i.e. a free surface), but still a primarily cylindrical object. The setup is subjected to transient heat loading (dT +20 -10C at room temperature), for a period of 6 months. I have a dataset regarding the temperature for the whole period and I am interested in simulating the temperature within the object. Now obviously running a coherent simulation with such a detailed dataset is beyond the computational capacity of mine, and I was wondering if there is a way to tweak heat transfer parameters and/or the setup to get my answers relatively accurately.